# PDO funcition Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I hope you help me out with this. I am really struggling to get this code fixed, it was coded for Mysql and now I want pass it into PDO.

```
$sql = " SELECT
        text_content
        FROM
        {$text_table}
        WHERE
        text_name = '{$this->database->escape($p_text_name)}'";

$queries = array(
    array(
        'sql'=> "{$sql} AND text_language_id='{$this->language['language_id']}' AND     text_page_id='{$sql_page_id}'",
        'error'     => false,
        'description'   => "seitenspezifisch, aktuelle Sprache {$this->language['language_locale_iso_short']}",
        ),
    array(
        'sql'=> "{$sql} AND text_language_id='{$this->language['language_id']}' AND text_page_id=0",
        'error' => iSYSTEM_CONFIG_LOG_LEVEL_LOW,
        'description'   => "global, aktuelle Sprache {$this->language['language_locale_iso_short']}",
    )
);

foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $result = $this->database->query_and_fetch($query['sql']);
    if ( $result !== false ) {  
        $found = true;
        break;
    } else {
        if ($query['error'] !== false) {
            log::error($query['error'], "Text {$p_text_name} not found ({$query['description']})");
        }
    }               
}
```

Ive tried this:

```
// Get single record as object
public function single(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}   

$this->database->query("SELECT text_content FROM {$text_table} WHERE text_name=:text_name");
$this->database->bind(':text_name',$p_text_name);

$sql = $this->database->single();
$sql = array();
```

im getting this error:

> Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Error messages like that normally identify the script file and line number ???

Comment: You are also using a library (that we know noting about) to do your database access? The issue could be in there. But from what you show us, there is no OBVIOUS place where that error may be happening !!

Comment: These 2 lines are wrong `$sql = $this->database->single();
$sql = array();` as you are destroying `$sql` which might contain a fetched row!!

Comment: the error is caused by @ 'sql'  => "{$sql} AND text_language_id='{$this->language['language_id']}' AND text_page_id='{$sql_page_id}'",

Comment: its says#Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Well then, as this is the only object `$this->language['language_id']` check what that ACTUALLY looks like

Comment: **as i try to iterate**@`foreach ($queries as $query) {
   $result = $this->database->query_and_fetch($query['sql']);`

Comment: any hint is really appreciated